# How do I replace the existing action of a(n?) UIButton?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

So far, I've been using

```
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(newAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

which adds an additional action (I think).  How can I replace the initial action with a new one?

Comment: I think a UIButton is acceptable, yes.

Comment: To remove all previous actions: ```[button1 removeTarget: nil action: NULL forControlEvents: UIControlEventAllEvents]``` - see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340825/uibutton-remove-all-target-actions

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can remove a target for a specific action like this:

```
[button1 removeTarget: self action: @selector(oldAction) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

Or, better yet, you can remove all targets from your button like this:

```
[button1 removeTarget: nil action: NULL forControlEvents: UIControlEventAllEvents]
```

Then, you can add your new target action:

```
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(newAction) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

That's pretty much it!

Answer (score 4):

You first have to remove the current action with removeTarget:action:forControlEvents: and then add the new one with addTarget:action:forControlEvents:.