# UIButton remove all target-actions

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have added multiple target-action-forControlEvents: to a UIButton. I'd like to remove all of these in one go without deallocating anything. I will then set new targets.

Is this possible and how do I go about it?

Answer (score 872, accepted):

Call [removeTarget:action:forControlEvents:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618248-removetarget), pass nil for the target, NULL for action, and use a control mask that sets all bits (UIControlEventAllEvents).

**Objective-C**

```
[someControl removeTarget:nil 
                   action:NULL 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
```

**Swift 2**

```
button.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, forControlEvents: .AllEvents)
```

**Swift 3 or higher**

```
button.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Here's the full link I think (ie. to the section): "http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/removeTarget:action:forControlEvents:"

Comment: progrmr's suggestion works of course. To add to the answer here is a code snippet like the one I needed:

[button removeTarget:nil
              action:NULL
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: Aside: the -allTargets instance method returns an NSSet of all the instance's targets (nil if none).

Comment: Perfect! exactly what i was looking for:D

Comment: Updated with Swift 2 and 3, as there are competing answers with exactly the same answer, differing only in language.

Comment: The link has changed to: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618248-removetarget

Answer (score 97):

@progrmr's answer in Swift 2:

```
button.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, forControlEvents: .AllEvents)
```

and Swift 3:

```
button.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)
```

Note: Swift doesn't have `NULL`, so I tested replacing it with `nil` and it seems to work fine.

Comment: For Swift 3: ".AllEvents" is now ".allEvents" (with a lowercase 'a'):
`removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)`

Comment: Regarding your NOTE: Actually, I believe you could pass either `nil` or `NULL` to **both** the first and second arguments in Objective-C too, and it will work. I believe both are defined as `(void*) 0` (or at the very least, evaluate as equals).

Comment: @Sasho I would love to see some statistics on how much source files sizes go down (on average) when upgrading to Swift 3 :-) (due to the new method/argument naming rules).

Comment: Since this is the same answer in a different language, and the language is not tagged in this question, it should be an edit to @progrmr's answer.

Answer (score 9):

Swift 3, 4, 5:

```
btnCancel.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.AllEvents)
```

Comment: please indicate which language are you covering

Comment: @JuanPabloBoero,it is swift

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 2:**

```
actionButton.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, forControlEvents: .AllEvents)
```

**Swift 3 & 4:**

```
actionButton.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)
```

**Objective-C:**

```
[actionButton removeTarget: nil action: NULL forControlEvents: UIControlEventAllEvents];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
- removeTarget:action:forControlEvents:
```

This method stops the delivery of events to the specified target object.

1. Specifying a **valid object** in the target parameter, this method stops the delivery of the specified events to all action methods associated with that object.
2. Specifying **nil** for the target parameter, this method prevents the delivery of those events to all action methods of all target objects

   **objective-c:**

   ```
   [_myButton removeTarget:  //any validObject (or) nil
                 action:nil
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
   ```

   **swift:**

   ```
   myButton.removeTarget(*validObject or nil*, action:nil, forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.AllEvents)
   ```

For more details https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/removeTarget:action:forControlEvents:

Answer (score 0):

you can change the selector if it is conditional.
see below example

you can remove all the targets first, then choose the selector and add it.

rateButton.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)

```
    let action = interview.isRated ? #selector(viewTapped(_:)) : #selector(rateTapped(_:))
            
    rateButton.addTarget(self, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)
```