# How to add a target action to a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've added a button to a specific UITableViewCell. When I select the button, I get a crash:

`ButtonTapped
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

At the beginning of `cellForRowAt`, I'm defining the button:

```
let myButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
myButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
myButton.tintColor = UIColor.yellow()
```

For the indexpath.row I attach the button like this:

`cell.accessoryView = myButton as UIView`

And the action `buttonTapped` tries to load a different ViewController.

I get confirmation that the button action worked (the routine was called).
The routine is as follows:

```
func buttonTapped() {
    print("ButtonTapped")

    let myPickerController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "picker") as? MyPickerController
    print("1")
    self.present(myPickerController!, animated: true)
    print("2")
}
```

As you can see from the log, I do see that the routine was called, but I do not see the print values 1 or 2 before the crash. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Remember table view cells are reused; not sure if it is wise to add a new button each time. Perhaps have each cell already _have_ a button, and re-configure it each time you dequeue a cell. You can reset all target/actions using `nil` arguments to `removeTarget...` : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3340840/433373

Comment: Good idea. I'll think I've tried that, but I'll check

Comment: Hmm. I have set the button as a global variable. I call it for the specific cell that needs it. I can see that the button activates the function, but then I still get the crash.. Other ideas welcome please.

Comment: Oh, so only one button exists at a time. You said you instantiate it "at the beginning of cellForRowAt", which is called once per cell the table needs to display. Even if there is one button that is reused, make sure you don't add the same target multiple times.

Comment: Oops. I had set it that way, but I took your point and moved creating the button to viewDidLoad. Sorry for confusion

Comment: If you only need one button at any time, shared among all cells, by all means create it once on setup, add the target/action there, and perhaps change the appearance/label text every time you reuse it (i.e., attach it to a cell). I believe you need to call `removeFromSuperview()` on the button before adding it as child of a different view (cell), otherwise an exception will be thrown by UIKit.

Answer (score 4):

Add target like,

```
 myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourControllerName.buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

then change your function like,

```
 func buttonTapped(sender : UIButton){

 ....
 }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Jigar.  The first line (addTarget) fails with ` Value of type 'MyViewController' has no member 'myButtonTapped'
  `

Comment: Have you define method within your controller with given name? like `buttonTapped`

Comment: i think your button action is in other view controller..?

Comment: "Have you define method within your controller with given name ".. Yes, the button works - I can see that the function is called.. The crash is right after that